# How to setup settings from a windows service at installation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, settings

I developed (VS2019 ) a Windows Service in C# using Topshelf. This service is intend to do some tasks periodically. To catch some logging of this service, I created a UI which connects to the service by using a WCF-contract. The service, the UI and the interaction between them runs very well, no problem.

I also created an installer for the UI so the end-user is able to use it on his desktop or other machine. For the service I also created an installer but I have some questions about it:

As said the service need to connect to a database ( MS SQL-Server) so I want the user ( the one who installs the service ) to be able to setup a connection-string, based on the name of the server, the name of the database and the connection type ( Windows / SQL authentication). When SQL Authentication is chosen, fields like username and password needs to become available, just like the SSMS connection dialog. As far as I can see this right now, there is no possibility to integrate it in the (default) installer from Visual Studio. Starting a form at the startup of the service is also not an option, because the service don't interact with the desktop ( despite of the setting in the Services).

An option can be sending the connection string and other parameters by using the UI, but when the service runs, it needs to have these parameters ( like connection-string). When the service is **not** running, the UI is not able to connect to the service.

What's the best approach to reach my goal and how can this be solved ?

Comment: Not sure why it is not possible to create an ui for connection string via installer from VS, but you can try to look at [Wix Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/) for example.

Comment: When I select SQL Authentication, the username and password boxes become visible, when selecting Windows Authentication they should be hidden ( or enabled). This can't be done by the custom dialogs.

Comment: You can try to split it in two windows in wizard, first to select auth type, second to fill in extra data. Still not sure if it is possible with VS default installer but should possible with Wix.

Comment: Unfortunately switching to Wix isn't an option, I'm stuck to the VS Installer ( company standard )